# trigger alert on div's mouse out

Tags: jquery

Im testing out something here,so please excuse the css rules.I have got a **ul** list in a div,and im trying to trigger a alert on the mouseout of the div but the alert triggers each time i mouseout the **li** items in the **ul**. Could some please tell me the reason behind it? I guess its something to so with bubbling but im not sure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<style>
#box{
cursor:pointer;width:300px;height:500px;background-color:#F1E0BB;
}

ul#myList{
list-style:none;padding-top:20px;
}

ul#myList li{
font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;height:40px;cursor:pointer;border:solid 1px #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box">
    <ul id="myList">
        <li>Item 11</li>
        <li>Item 12</li>
        <li>Item 13</li>
        <li>Item 14</li>
        <li>Item 15</li>
    </ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Jquery script i used

```
$('#box').mouseout(function(){

alert("ccc");

})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`mouseleave` event](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) here instead, which doesn't fire when leaving children:

```
$('#box').mouseleave(function(){
  alert("ccc");
});
```

You're assumption about bubbling is correct, it's those child elements bubbling up that's triggering your handler.  From the [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) docs:

> The `mouseleave` event differs from `mouseout` in the way it handles event bubbling. If `mouseout` were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved out of the **Inner** element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The `mouseleave` event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the **Outer** element, but not the **Inner** element.

Comment: mate u r a genius,thanks a lot !! i have to wait till 12 mins to flag this as answered bcos it took u only less than a min to answer it !

Comment: Mousenter and mouseleave are unfortunately only supported by MSIE, according to Quirksmode: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html#t28

Comment: @David - jQuery simulates these in all browsers, so this will work everywhere.